# failed to install docker on Debian 8

Tags: debian, apt, docker, debian-jessie

This is the first time I deal with Debian, and I need a docker. I was following https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/debian/ to get it installed, however I faced the error:

```
% apt-get update
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20160123-19:03] jessie InRelease
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20160123-19:03] jessie Release.gpg
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20160123-19:03] jessie Release
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20160123-19:03] jessie/contrib amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20160123-19:03] jessie/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20160123-19:03] jessie/contrib Translation-en_CA
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20160123-19:03] jessie/main Translation-en_CA
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Sources
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Translation-en
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
% apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package apt-transport-https
%
```

**UPDATE**
As recommended, I updated `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
% cat /etc/apt/sources.list
#
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
```

However `apt-cache show apt-transport-https` returns error (Unable to locate package apt-transport-https), `and apt-get install apt-transport-https` returns the same fail as before.

What should I be looking at to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: You didn't _finish_ updating your repositories.

Comment: @Michaeil, can you tell me what exactly I have missed? I think all the required repos are liste in sources.list

Comment: You don't have the Debian jessie repo. You only have the jessie updates repo (and listed twice).

Comment: I updated sources.list, please see my original post. However still doesn't help.

Comment: If you're still experiencing this problem, please do `apt-get update` and provide the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package apt-transport-https is available in the official repositories (checked with `apt-cache show apt-transport-https`) but does not seem to be included on the DVD you have used for installation.

Modifying your sources.list to use internet repositories instead of the DVD should fix it. See also here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16370/apt-get-prompts-for-cds-when-installing-packages-how-do-i-make-it-stop